# find max k sequence - is it greedy?

Tags: algorithms, greedy-algorithms

The original problem statement is:

> > Given a sequence of numbers $A[1..n]$, find $k < n$ consecutive numbers such that the sum of these $k$ numbers is maximized where $k$ is a positive integer given together with the sequence. Specifically, we want the index $i$ such that $A[i+1..i+k]$ is the largest.
> >     Design $O(n)$ greedy algorithm to solve this problem.

Because my solution is broken up into an initialization step followed by the greedy step, I think this algorithm in general will not classify as greedy. On the other hand, I would argue the initialization step does not invalidate the classification of this algorithm as greedy. Since I'm the student and not the teacher in this case, I seek outside perspective.

My solution idea is to compare every $k$ sub series of elements against the previous greatest sub series of $k$ elements, updating $T$ when a new greater sub series is found. Temporary sub series are stored in lowercase $t$ for comparison. For every iteration in the greedy step, I replace $t$ by removing the previous first element in $t$ and add the new next element in iteration thus constantly having an updated sum of the $k$ sub sequence for comparison against the greatest current sub sequence in $T$.

Proof of correctness isn't what I seek. I wish to know if my implementation below is classifiable as a greedy algorithm?

```
def find_max_k_sequence(A, k):
    T = 0 # running total
    m = k-1 # marks the index at end of max sequence
    i = 0

    # initial sum 0 to k
    while i < k:
        T += A[i]
        i +=1

    # greedy remaining steps
    n = len(A)
    t = T
    while i < n:
        t = t - A[i - k] + A[i]
        if t > T:
            T = t
            m = i
        i += 1

    return m-k+1, m, T

A = [1,2,1,3,1,4]
print(find_max_k_sequence(A, 3))

>> (3, 5, 8)
```

Comment: The natural algorithm for solving this problem is *not* greedy. I suggest you ignore this instruction.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Would you say I have solved this naturally? If not, can you share an alternative solution? I'm certainly interested in a more optimal solution. But, ultimately, I want to know is if this is in fact regarded as a greedy solution implemented by me or not.

Comment: There is essentially only one efficient solution, which is what you did, but it's not greedy. It's just a bad question.